# Running validation because of mismatched checksum for liferay-target-platform

Tags: liferay

Every time I start Liferay, I get:

```
Running validation because of mismatched checksum for liferay-target-platform
LPKG validation time 01:59s
```

How can I avoid wasting these 2 minutes every time I restart?

Full message with timestamps and fluff:

```
03:33:43,463 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: e0662c6f-3135-0017-1c4b-98e88b99c01c][LPKGIndexValidator:159] Running validation because of mismatched checksum for liferay-target-platform
03:35:40,202 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: e0662c6f-3135-0017-1c4b-98e88b99c01c][LPKGIndexValidator:266] LPKG validation time 01:59s
```

[Relevant Liferay source code: LPKGIndexValidator.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/static/portal-lpkg-deployer/portal-lpkg-deployer/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/lpkg/deployer/internal/LPKGIndexValidator.java)

Comment: Might be related: `Running validation because expected keys: [Liferay+Collaboration, Liferay+Connected+Services+Client, Liferay+Documentum+Connector, Liferay+Forms+and+Workflow, Liferay+Foundation, Liferay+Marketplace, Liferay+Sharepoint+Connector, Liferay+Static, Liferay+Sync+Connector, Liferay+Web+Experience, liferay-target-platform] do not match actual keys: [...]` with Liferay DXP 7 SP4 FP30

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at [the Liferay blog.](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/disabling-lpkg-index-validation) To avoid validation you can try to set

```
module.framework.properties.lpkg.index.validator.enabled=false
```

in your `portal-ext.properties` file. However, as mentioned in the blog post, this is not recommended on production environments.